# driver for graphic card NVIDIA GeForce GT 820M?

Tags: nvidia

I recently purchased dell laptop with the graphic card specification as provided above but could not get the required driver ? Please help anyone from Ubuntu community and please leave link if any for the same...!
I have downloaded from their official site but is yet after double clickin and all yet not able to figure my way out

Comment: you can easily install the 331 driver needed from the ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/installing-nvidia-drivers from more information.

Answer (score 1):

[Nvidia has a pretty good support site](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/73221/en-us) and lists drivers for Linux in both 32 and 64 bit versions - have you tried their support pages yet?

Comment: Sir trying your link i have downloaded the given file ; but i don't know how to install it and where to install it?

Comment: sir i downloaded whatbthey gave but after double clickin it was not installed

Comment: still when i write this code in my terminal lspci | grep VGA it still shows mine internal graphic card of intel

Comment: On the same webpage as the download, is a tab with reasonably good instructions for installation of the drivers.